# Cassandra - Update And Select Field Greater Than

Tags: java, cassandra, cassandra-2.0, bigdata, nosql

I am new to cassandra. I am in need to update a field in table and also select the data from that table by filtering that field > (greater) than condition. How can i create a table to support that. Can anyone help me on this?

### For Eg:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
   id uuid,
   title text,
   start_date timeuuid,   
   PRIMARY KEY (id, start_date)
)
```

In the above table i want to be able to execute both the query below,

```
update test set start_date = 04940b5e-00a2-11e6-afcd-063929a48e12 WHERE id = 04940b5e-00a2-11e6-afcd-063929a48e11;

select * from test where start_date > 04940b5e-00a2-11e6-afcd-063929a48e11 ALLOW FILTERING;
```

But in the above query it will support only second one. (i.e) >

If i remove the start_date from clustering key then it will support the update query and not the > query.

But i want that both query to get executed. Please anyone guide me on this to make it work.

Comment: timeuuid is like a timestamp, it can't be a string.

Comment: i just given sample value. Its a timeuuid only. But both func should work

Comment: I don't see why the update would not work. If start_date was in the primary key it would be a problem but for a clustering key it should be ok

Comment: Is my create table is correct?

Comment: you have id as a partition key, and in a partition key the row are ordered by date. In my opinion, if you need to query by date, the best is to partition by date if you can. In your case, you need to query every partition to have a result

Comment: have a look here [http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/a-deep-look-to-the-cql-where-clause ]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this, you have two solutions :

- set (id, start_date) as primary key. You can't perform here the first
  query, because it's like insert a new data : you put a new primary
  key. But you can delete the line you want update, and insert another
  one
- create two tables with the two schemas, that's allow you to perform
  the two requests. If you want a transactional insertion, you can use
  batch (see here :
  https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/batch_r.html).
  You will be sure that both of your datas will be insert.

However, use 'ALLOW FILTERING' is not a good idea : it has really bad perfomances. Use it only if you have no other choices, for few requests that don't need performances.